# Cannot encrypt using EncryptContent in NiFi

Tags: encryption, apache-nifi, public-key-encryption, pgp, openpgp

I am using a public ASCII armored key file generated via the command :

`gpg --output PG1ar_en_pub.asc --armor --export "xxxxx@xxxx.com"`

In Nifi Encrypt content processor, I have setup the following configuration:
[image]

When I run this, I am getting the below error:

```
EncryptContent[id=66ef350e-65aa-1cc0-ac66-67ac1ea0bb5e] Cannot encrypt StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=e7fc0a5a-f30b-4139-8237-7700b98bbdc8,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1619433115884-599196, container=default, section=156], offset=0, length=52],offset=0,name=e7fc0a5a-f30b-4139-8237-7700b98bbdc8,size=52] - : Invalid public keyring - invalid header encountered
```

Comment: Wow, two years, nine months—crickets. I'm in the same boat. Did you ever get this worked out?